# Running terminal commands from java (using Eclipse)

Tags: java, windows, macos, git, terminal

I am playing around with some GIT commands in terminal, but I want to write a java program to automate the process.Please note I am not writing a program straight into a terminal. I am writing it in eclipse. This following code works on windows, but not MAC. How should I change it to run on MAC?

```
import java.io.*;


public class NewClass {



public static void main(String[] args) {  
    try {  
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("GIT");  
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(  
                            new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));  
        String line = null;  
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
            System.out.println(line);  
        }  
    } catch (IOException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
}
```

}

Comment: Obvious question: Does simply typing `GIT` in the mac console works?

Comment: Try looking here: https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#platform-mac

Answer (score 1):

"GIT" should be "git" for case sensitive systems like Mac OS.  Note that without arguments, this will only give you a listing of the git syntax.

Comment: Thank you, but that wasn't the issue, as I have tried different commands" This works perfectly on Windows, so the command should't be the problem.

Comment: It works on Windows because commands are not case sensitive on Windows.  On Windows, an upper case "GIT" command means the same thing as a lower case "git" command.  On Mac OS, they mean different things.

Comment: I have been using different commands, just typed this with a mistake to shorten the code

Comment: I'm not sure OSX actually is case sensitive (any more?)... for example "GIT" actually does seem to work, though it still would not on linux.

Comment: @ChrisStratton valid point.  OS X isn't really case insensitive, but it's also not strictly case sensitive like linux.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the basic steps outlined in this CS article from Princeton ([How to run Java Program on a Mac](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr04/cos126/hello/mac.html))

Comment: Please not that I am not writing  a program straight in to a terminal. It is done in Eclipse.